# Bug in OSX mkdir -p?

Tags: macos, bash

If I issue 'mkdir A'  then all is well.

But then 'mkdir a' does not create the sub-directory

although 'mkdir c' is fine.

Any ideas ?

Comment: In order to have the same directory/file name in differing case at the same level the volume has to be formatted "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)" or "(Case-sensitive, Journaled)", which cannot be done nondestructively after the fact. Greg Tarsa's comments in his answer only apply to a default format, otherwise he's wrong in the statements made! That said, there are pros and cons to using a case-sensitive format and better left to a different discussion.

Answer (score 4):

OS X, or rather, the file system HFS+ is (by default) case-blind.  It honors the case you create the name with, but will match in a case-blind manner.  You cannot create directories that have the same letters in upper and lower case.

Comment: Thanks -- never noticed that in quite a few years!

Comment: While the default format is case-insensitive nonetheless what you've said is not totally true as one can format a volume as "Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive)" or "(Case-sensitive, Journaled)". and then what the OP tried would have worked.  That said, there are pros and cons to using a case-sensitive format and better left to a different discussion.

Comment: You can run `diskutil info /` and check the `File System Personality` and `Name (User Visible)` entries to see if the file system is case sensitive (it is case insensitive if it doesn't mention anything about case sensitivity). You can also run `diskutil listFilesystems` to get a list of partition formats `diskutil` can produce on your system.

Comment: I agree that this is not totally true, but it is true in the default configuration and clearly true given the problem description in this question.  Having said that, it is great to know about the tools for checking the actual configuration and the steps for making a truly case-sensitive file system.  Thanks!